# Conditionally make a field readonly in Statamic

Tags: statamic

I would like to make a specific field of a blueprint readonly for some users in Statamic 3.3. Other users should be able to edit the field.

I cannot find anything in the docs. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in to Statamic to do this. However, maybe the [Restrict Fields](https://statamic.com/addons/thoughtco/restrict-fields) addon might do what you want.